# AWS Cert Mgr - How to create root CA certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, certificate, aws-certificate-manager

In the below option from AWS Certificate manager, I have an option to create **subordinate CA** but not **root CA**,

### [image]

Goal is to first create **root CA** certificate and then create **sub-ordinate CA** that is signed(issued) by root CA's private key.

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaCreateCa.html) also talks about creating subordinate CA but not about root CA

---

Does AWS certification manager allow creating private root CA? if yes, How to create private root CA with AWS Certification manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This changed today. ACM Private CA now supports creating roots and subordinates.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=6894

Comment: I see that option now... and I created one

Answer (score 1):

To use AWS ACM Private Certificate Authority, you must already have an intermediate or root CA available in your organization. Once you create the subordinate CA, you will generate a CSR and sign it with your certificate. This service is a low-cost solution for managing the issuance and renewals of private certificates.

If your goal is to create a Root CA that the world will accept for SSL certificates, that is going to be a very difficult challenge. Very few companies qualify to be a Certificate Authority and this requires a big investment in infrastructure, security, policies, and procedures.

Comment: We have a root CA within our organization. I have created intermediate CA. root CA is in my key store on MAC. How to sign a CSR with root CA? Do I need to just export root CA to a file(`.cer`) and then import at `Certificate chain` option?

Comment: When you create the subordinate CA, you will next create a CSR. Then you will sign the CSR with your certificate.

Comment: Yes I created A CSR for subordinate CA, and then I need to import a file in  `Certificate body` and then `Certificate chain` section. I am **stuck** here. From my side, I have `Entrust root CA` certificate in my key store(`.cer` file). What should I import in `Certificate body` and `Certificate chain`?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by import a file.What documentation are you following? This AWS documentation covers this in detail; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaCreateCa.html

Comment: Ah... it says... `Obtain a signed certificate from the parent of this certificate authority (CA). Submit the following certificate signing request (CSR) to the parent CA. Have the parent CA sign it and create a certificate. Click 'Next' when you have the signed certificate and are ready to import it. `

Comment: I don't know what infrastructure you have set up. You sign the CSR which creates another certificate. You import this new certificate (the output from signing). Please create a NEW question for further help providing specific details on what you have setup.